# Component auth has not been registered yet at Provider.initialize

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am working on an app and using firebase authentication and at first it worked but after some time is shows this error.

> Uncaught Error: Component auth has not been registered yet
>
> at Provider.initialize
>
> at initializeAuth
>
> at getAuth
>
> at index.js:32:14

How can I solve it?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"